# Display post date also if the date it's the same for each post

Tags: php, theme-development, themes

I have this code to display a news feed. It will load only six entries and works fine. I've noticed that the date ofe the posts are showed only on one post, Is possible to show the date for each post loaded also if the date is the same?

```
<!-- news -->
<div class="container-fluid p-0" id="news">
  <div class="row m-0">
<?php $news = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'category' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 6 ) ); ?>
<?php if( $news->have_posts() ): while( $news->have_posts() ): $news->the_post(); ?> 
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center p-0">
      <a class="text-decoration-none text-white stretched-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100 h-100" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <p><?php the_date(); ?></p>
          <h4 class=""><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
          <h4 class="btn btn-outline-light text-uppercase rounded-0"><?php _e('Leggi'); ?></h4>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="overlay position-absolute"></div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if changing `the_date();` to `echo get_the_date();`. It will display the date individually.

Because [the_date()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_date/) have a checking of same date or not. If it is the same date as previous post, it will output nothing. So by manually doing the output with [get_the_date()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/), it will by pass the checking.

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0" id="news">
  <div class="row m-0">
<?php $news = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'category' => 'news', 'posts_per_page' => 6 ) ); ?>
<?php if( $news->have_posts() ): while( $news->have_posts() ): $news->the_post(); ?> 
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 text-center p-0">
      <a class="text-decoration-none text-white stretched-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100 h-100" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
        <div class="card-img-overlay">
          <p><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></p>
          <h4 class=""><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
          <h4 class="btn btn-outline-light text-uppercase rounded-0"><?php _e('Leggi'); ?></h4>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="overlay position-absolute"></div>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this.